# Finding contrapositive of the definition of causal system

Tags: logic, quantifiers

We say a system is causal if and only if for any $x_1(t) , x_2(t)$ and $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$
$$x_1(t) = x_2(t) , \ \ \ \forall t\lt t_0 \implies Lx_1(t) = Lx_2(t), \ \ \ \forall t \lt t_0$$ In words, it means that the output of $L$ at any time depends only on past values of input. Note that $x_1,x_2 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ are complex-valued functions of a real variable. I'm trying to find the contrapositive of the above proposition. I think the answer is

> There exists $x_1(t) , x_2(t)$ and $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\exists t\lt t_0 : \ \ Lx_1(t) \not= Lx_2(t) \implies \ \ \ \exists t\lt t_0 : x_1(t)\not = x_2(t) $$

I don't know if this is really meaningful. Maybe "There exists" should be replaced by "For all". Multiple quantifiers complicate the problem. So what's the correct answer?

Comment: Are $x_1$ and $x_2$ functions of $t$? If so, what do you mean when you say "for any $x_1(t)$, $x_2(t)$"?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Yes, they are functions of $t$. By that I mean for any inputs $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$. I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_system#:~:text=In%20control%20theory%2C%20a%20causal,the%20input%20for%20values%20of%20.) explains what I mean.

Comment: The contrapositive is not the negative. So $\forall t_0, \forall x_i, (A\implies B)$ becomes $\forall t_0,\forall x_i, (not B\implies not A)$.

Comment: @Chrystomath Thanks. Would you write the complete definition in the logical form? My main problem is writing the full definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contrapositive of the statement $$\forall t_0\in\mathbb{R},\ \forall x_1,x_2\in C(\mathbb{R}),\quad(\forall t<t_0,x_1(t)=x_2(t))\implies(\forall t<t_0,Lx_1(t)=Lx_2(t))$$ is
$$\forall t_0\in\mathbb{R},\ \forall x_1,x_2\in C(\mathbb{R}),\quad(\exists t<t_0,Lx_1(t)\ne x_2(t))\implies(\exists t<t_0,x_1(t)\ne x_2(t))$$

[I'm assuming the functions $x_i(t)$ belong to $C(\mathbb{R})$; of course, this can be changed to whatever space they belong to.]

Comment: When we say $(\exists t<t_0,Lx_1(t)\ne x_2(t))\implies(\exists t<t_0,x_1(t)\ne x_2(t))$ the $t$'s in the premise and conclusion are the same or they can be different?

Comment: That would depend whether the original statement was $(\forall t<t_0 A)\implies(\forall t<t_0 B)$ or $\forall t<t_0 (A\implies B)$. As written, it is the former.

Comment: What's the difference between $(\forall t<t_0 A)\implies(\forall t<t_0 B)$ and $\forall t<t_0 (A\implies B)$? They seem same to me.

Comment: They're not: $(\forall t, t=0)\Rightarrow(\forall t, t=1)$ is true (False $\Rightarrow$ False), but $\forall t, (t=0\Rightarrow t=1)$ is false.